# What is "(other)" location, "(other)" app version appers in Firebase Analytics StreamView of my android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Sometimes I see lots of other location and other app version in firebase streamview? I've searched the web and SO but can't find anything also nothing in google docs? I know that when I released a new version of android app google bots install and test application but google bots appear as "Unknown Location" and also can see the version they are using. So they should't be google bots?
So, what is all that (other) things?

[image: location]

[image: app version]

Comment: Hi, how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @alfalfa I couldn't resolve but others are disappeared for a while. But now, sometimes I see empty locations. Maybe they're also google's test devices that test apps security, performance, stability, etc.